# Is there any possibility to deal with larger precision of Complex data type in c#?

Tags: c#, integer, double

I'm writing program which use complex data type, but it's too small for my problem. I know it's just double data type for both real and imaginary members, but is it possible to keep numbers as big as 10^30? I was thinking about about connecting complex struct with big integer type (because I don't use floating-point numbers), but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Double goes way beyond 10^30, but is your question about range or accuracy?

Comment: See the [double documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.8) which states that it can represent numbers as big as 10^308 with a precision of 15 decimal digits.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I meant precision, I cannot store number such as 123000001234555043430022222034333443344

Answer (score 0):

Operate on the number as a string and work out calculations long form digit by digit.

Comment: Why doing it the most complicated way? If you want to calculate with arbitrarily large numbers you would normally use the BigInteger struct. As for non-integer numbers these can for most calculations just be represented as such integers too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I made a structure with two BigInteger members, one for real and second for imaginary part. Ofc this solution need to create new functions for complex operations.
For example adding 2 Complex (I named struct as "BigComplex")

```
BigComplex add(BigComplex x, BigComplex y)
{
    BigComplex z;
    z.Real = x.Real + y.Real;
    z.Imaginary = x.Imaginary + y.Imaginary;
    return z;
}
```